# Dependency Injection создает экземпляры разных типов

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, кэширование, redis, dependency-injection

У меня есть сервис по работе с JWT

```
public class JwtService : IJwtService
{
    private IDistributedCache cache;
    private IHttpContextAccessor httpContext;
    private IOptions<JwtOptions> jwtOptions;
    private MyContext context;
    private ILogger<JwtService> logger;

    public JwtService(MyContext context, IDistributedCache cache,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContext, IOptions<JwtOptions> jwtOptions, ILogger<JwtService> logger)
    {
        this.cache = cache;
        this.httpContext = httpContext;
        this.jwtOptions = jwtOptions;
        this.context = context;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    private string GetCurrentJwtString()
    {            
        StringValues header = httpContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["authorization"];            
        return StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(header) ? string.Empty : header.Single().Split(" ").Last();
    }

    public async Task<bool> IsActiveCurrentJwtAsync()
    {
        return await IsActiveJwtAsync(GetCurrentJwtString());
    }

    public async Task DeactivateCurrentJwtAsync()
    {            
        await DeactivateJwtAsync(GetCurrentJwtString());
    }

    public async Task DeactivateJwtAsync(string token)
    {                      
        await cache.SetStringAsync(token, "diactivated", new DistributedCacheEntryOptions()
        {
            AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(jwtOptions.Value.ExpiryMinutes)
        });                           
    }               

    public async Task<bool> IsActiveJwtAsync(string token)
    {                              
        return await cache.GetStringAsync(token) == null;
    }
```

И есть два места в проекте, которые взаимодействуют с этим сервисом:

Первое. В контроллере пользователя при выходе из аккаунта я вызываю метод деактивации токена, который просто заносит токен в кэш.

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    IJwtService jwtServ;
    IUserService userServ;
    public UserController(IJwtService jwtServ, IUserService userServ)
    {
        this.jwtServ = jwtServ;
        this.userServ = userServ;
    }        

    [ActionName("Logout")]
    public async Task Logout()
    {
        await jwtServ.DeactivateCurrentJwtAsync();
    }
}
```

И второе: 
В классе Startup в настройке аутентификации после валидации токена я проверяю, есть ли он в кэше или нет.

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(option =>
        {
            option.Configuration = Configuration["Redis:Address"];
            option.InstanceName = "maelstorm";
        });

services
        .AddAuthentication(options => {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = jwtSchemeName;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = jwtSchemeName;                                           
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(jwtSchemeName, jwtBearerOptions => {                    
            jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {                        
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signingDecodingKey.GetKey(),
                TokenDecryptionKey = encryptingDecodingKey.GetKey(),

                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)                        
            };                    
            var servProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var jwtService = servProvider.GetService<IJwtService>();
            jwtBearerOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {                            
                OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {                            
                    if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                    {
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
                    }                                                        
                    return Task.CompletedTask;                            
                },
                OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                {                            
                    if(! await jwtService.IsActiveCurrentJwtAsync())
                    {
                        context.Fail("Token is not active");                                                                                      
                    }                                    
                }                                                                       
            };
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в первом случае переменная cache в JWTService имеет тип `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.MemoryDistributedCache`,а во втором - `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.RedisCachе`. Получается, что метод деактивации токена записывает токен в один кэш, а метод проверки пытается достать из другого и поэтому ничего не работает. Почему механизм внедрения зависимостей создает экземпляры разных типов? Каким образом сделать так, чтобы всегда использовался лишь Redis в качестве кэша?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Механизм внедрения зависимостей создаёт разные зависимости потому что у вас два разных ServiceProvider: один был создан фреймворком, а другой создали вы сами:

```
            // Не делайте так!
            var servProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var jwtService = servProvider.GetService<IJwtService>();
```

Вместо того, чтобы вызывать случайные методы, вам надо получить доступ к системному ServiceProvider. Например, вот так:

```
                OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                {
                    var jwtService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IJwtService>();
                    // ...
                }
```